# How can I avoid my import crashing with a Fatal Error due to an existing external ID?

Tags: import, duplicate-contacts, external-id

I've had a few separate imports crash with a fatal error in the last month:

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
>   DB Error: already exists
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/user/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107

In my case it seems to have something to do with external IDs that already exist in the database and are also in the import file. How can I avoid having imports fatally die in the middle of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jamie McClelland, there is a patch available to make this more user-friendly. At some point hopefully it will be merged into core.

- JIRA: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19664
- PR: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9410

With this patch applied, instead of a fatal error, the import will continue and the problem rows will be pulled out in an error file at the end.